# javascript window.location fake callback

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I need to make a fake `window.location = "testCall"` call in order to generate an event to bypass parameters on a mobile device. Works as native, however, I need then to dissmiss a NotFound exception or mainly dissmiss a fake window.location call. Possible? Thank you

Comment: This would only work if the page returned a 400 error, which, in many cases, it won't.

Comment: basicly I must simulate window.location event without redirecting to...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'location').configurable === false
```

in Chrome and Safari (and I presume in other browsers). So seems like you can't change the native behavior.

If it behaved as a normal EcmaScript 5 property and `configurable` was set to `true` than you could have done something like that:

```
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'location');
var setter = descriptor.set; // Doesn't exist although it should in spirit of ES5

descriptor.set = function (newLocation) {
    try {
        setter(newLocation);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Location error: ', newLocation, e);
    }
};

// The line below will throw exception in real browser :(
// TypeError: Cannot redefine property: location
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', descriptor);
```

I hope browser vendors migrate all their *magical* properties and objects to standard EcmaScript mechanics but at the moment we are out of luck.